# Mule: Extracting connector-ref to properties file

Tags: mule

I have a line that reads like this in my flow:

```
<jms:inbound-endpoint queue="${queue.name}" connector-ref="${inbound.connector}" doc:name="Inbound Endpoint">
```

Where the "${inbound.connector}" property refers to a string in my properties file:

```
inbound.connector=Active_MQ
```

The reason I am doing this is because the connector-ref will vary depending on the environment.  Sometimes it will be an Active_MQ connector, sometimes it will be a JMS Connector.

The properties file is under src/main/resources, as it should be.  I have other properties in the flow that are read from the properties file just fine, such as the "queue.name" property.  However, for some reason when I try to start Mule it is returning an error saying:

```
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named '${inbound.connector}' is defined.
```

As far as I know the connector-ref value is just a string, so this should work in theory.  I don't understand this error.  Is the connector-ref in fact not a string, and this approach is illegal?

Answer (score 0):

Internally mule runtime creates/initializes all the connector objects(spring bean) like HTTP Connectors, DATASOURCE connectors and various other connector's when the application comes up. All these connectors are nothing but a spring beans as Mule is written on top of Springframework. So it is not possible to make it dynamic by passing in a string value where it expects a object.